# Is it possible to keep a MacOS application window "Always in the Back"?

Tags: macos, window-manager

There seems to exist options for keeping MacOS application windows 'Always on Top'.

But is it possible via some method (e.g. a third party utility) to set an application window to be 'Always in the Back', having *all* other windows float on top of it, while still enabling the cursor to be editing/browsing the application in the back?

For example in the screenshot below, to edit the Microsoft Word document in this window configuration, I would have to click on its window, and that would hide the TextEdit window.

NB: I realize that setting TextEdit to 'Always on Top' would achieve the same effect, however the question is if an application can be set to be in the back of *all* other applications – preferably not to set all other applications to 'Always be on Top'. Also, please note that I'm not asking about splitting the screen real estate between the two apps (that's off topic).

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Without a third party application, I don't think you can make an app invisible to 'bring to front' or 'make active'...

However, An option is the use of the Command Key.[image: animation of background activity]

By holding down the Command key while in an active application, you can interact with the application behind it without activating it.

As you can see in the gif, the Terminal is the active application, but I can still interact with the Browser behind it without losing the focus of the active app.